# how to add rich snippets to wordpress with the plugin

Tags: wordpress, schema.org

I am using WordPress & tried a lot of plugins to add reviews on google and add schema.org in my website. But still i am unable to show the review result on google page. If there any plugins to show the result correctly then please describe about that.

There's a lot of plugins which is showing that after install everything is easy and the result will show on google but every time i have wast my time to test them all.

I have test my site url using google webmaster tools, there's no error on my site, But still i can's show the review on google search page like...
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfMWJ.png)

Comment: Are you looking out for help to find a plugin, then I think you are at the wrong place.

Comment: @Yasser I am not looking for a plugin. I have added Schema markup on my post & also added the ratting on this post  with schema protocol. After adding the markup i have tested my post url on Google Webmaster tools, There's no error shown to me for my post URL. But still i am unable to see the review result on google search page. So now what should i do? :O 

My post url is:- http://www.inspiringearthlings.com/whats-weight-loss-shake